# jquery ajax search form

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a REST Url `http://localhost/issues` presenting me a search form for querying issues of a bug tracker system. The search form has a textfield with `name="f"`. The action of the form is `action="/issues"` and the `method=GET`. So if I type "foobar" into the textfield, I am getting redirected to `http://localhost/issues?f=foobar`.

To prevent page reload, I use AJAX with jquery. So I used `$(document).on('submit',...)` to bind an AJAX query function to the submit function of the form. I used firebug to proove, that jquery sends the request and no page reload is taken. I also have a function to fill results of the response into my site presented in the browser. Everything works fine for the first search attempt.

But if I type another search string "anotherfoobar" into the textfield and resend the request, the request URL is `http://localhost/issues?f=foobar&f=anotherfoobar`, so the search parameter is only appended to the URL, not updatedas I thought it would happen.

I've read about "hashing" the URL parameters to prevent this behaviour here on stackoverflow, but do not fully understand what and why this is happening and what "hashing" means exactly. Perhaps it's not the right solution for me. So I kindly ask someone to explain me how I can solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it! Don't ask how exactly, what I did was the following:

The AJAX response is the whole Web page as I would get it with a page reload. with jquery I select a div which includes the search form AND the results.

I simply defined a div only for the results, and update only the content of the results div. After doing so, everything works fine, and the results div updates with multiple search attempts.

Another case of not knowing what I do, but I do it fine ;)

Perhaps someone still can explain me my error so wisdom can rise.